# Sort column with numbers and characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I have a column which contains a data series, for example:

```
100
100a
100b
101
102
103...
101a
101b, etc.
```

I need them to be in the following order:

```
100
101
102
103...
100a
100b
101a
101b, etc.
```

Comment: Is it always just a single character after the numeric portion?

Comment: yes, it is always a character

Answer (score 1):

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RIGHT(YourColumn,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         YourColumn
```